# Save Failed Could not initialize class org.eclipse.core.internal.utils.UniversalUniqueIdentifier

Tags: android, eclipse

I m getting this error msg whenever going to save any of change in any file . I m using
Android Developer Tool Build: v22.3.0-887826 . Plz give solution ....
thxs in advance...

Comment: Have you updated your SDK ?

Comment: Yap.... it is upto date....